# Sass/Compass and Sprites: How do I pick random images for a page-specific sprite?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, css-sprites, compass-sass

I am using sass/compass and want to take advantage of compass's sprite feature. The project I am on is in a long-standing application where the images are all scattered around in the images folder.

For example, let's say I have two pages, page-a.html and page-b.html which have the following images on each page:

```
page-a.html:
  /images/foo/bar.png
  /images/elvis-presley.png

page-b.html
  /images/foo/bar.png
  /images/people/david-hasselhoff.png
```

The [compass spriting tutorial](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) suggests that all the images **must** be in the same directory. Given the above scenario, that is not possible because /images/foo/bar.png is used for both pages (but not necessarily every page of the site). So, in this case I would either have to:

1. duplicate the images/foo/bar.png image and place a copy into a folder specific to each page or
2. symlink the image in each page specific folder to a shared location where the file actually sits

Neither of these options are desirable and would easily prevent me from continuing this sprite optimization attempt.

What I need to know is whether it is possible for compass to create a sprite from several images **not** in the same folder.

Comment: Are you planning on replacing every image on the site with a sprite?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@import "images/**/*.png";

@each $file in bar, elvis-presley, david-hasselhoff {
    .sprite.#{$file} {
        @include flags-sprite($file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want the images to change every time the page reloads, then that's impossible with pure css because sass is compiled and not evaluated on every request.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that is not exactly what I was asking. I reworded my question to hopefully be more clear.

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking is not possible.

Are you planning on replacing the images you mentioned with css sprites? If so, every page would reference the compiled sprite image. The individual image files would no longer be used for any page, so it wouldn't matter where they are in the file system.

Comment: I want page specific sprites to go in to page specific css files, so yes, I would be replacing bar.png and elvis-presley.png with a single sprite for use only with page-a.html. Completely separate from that I want to replace bar.png and david-hasselhoff.png with a sprite specific to page-b.html. How is it that by planning to replace the images with a sprite they would be referenced on every page?

Comment: Additionally, the individual image files would no longer be used on any one page but they would be needed to compile new sprites. There lies the problem, to compile sprites for both pages, I would need either 2 copies of the same image (bar.png) or the ability compile a sprite from images in separate directories.